# Does the limit of $(-1)^x$ as $x \to \infty$ exist?

Tags: real-analysis

Consider the function $f(x)=(-1)^x$, defined with domain as a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$. Firstly, how do we find the domain of $f$? I only know that at fractional powers $1/2, 3/2$, or anything with $p/q$ such that $\gcd(p,q)=1$ and $2|q$, the function is not defined. (Of course at the integers the function is defined)

Secondly, I conjecture from the result that $\lim_{n \to \infty}\ (-1)^n$ does not exist that 
$$\lim_{x \to \infty}\ (-1)^x$$
also does not exist. 
How do I show it?

Comment: If that set of $\;x\;$ for which the function is""defined"" contains  some rational of the form $\;\frac{p}{2n}\;,\;\;p\;$ is odd, you're going to have to know what to do with an even square of a negative number within the real numbers...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you want to work in the real numbers, you *could* say that the domain of the function is the set
$$
\left\{
x\in\mathbb{Q}:x=\frac{r}{s}, s>0, \text{$s$ odd}
\right\}
$$
This is quite a big set and it contains all natural numbers; however
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}(-1)^{2n}=1,
\qquad
\lim_{n\to\infty}(-1)^{2n+1}=-1,
$$
so what you can say is that, no, the limit doesn't exist.

I'd simply say that the function $x\mapsto a^x$ on the reals is defined only for $a>0$, so the problem is meaningless in this case.

Answer (score 1):

HINT

I would say

$e^{i\pi}=-1 \Rightarrow (-1)^x = e^{i \pi x} = \cos \pi x + i\sin \pi x$

As a real function domain and range = a empty set.